# FORTRAN: undefined reference to main in crt1.o in function '_start'

Tags: fortran, mpi, ubuntu-12.04, gfortran

I have a compile error I cannot understand, I think it is complaining about a function in one of the libraries. I do not get this error if I compile on Windows or Redhat, only on my Ubuntu 12.04.
Please help me find the source of this problem, I've seen other posts on the net but no solution.

Here's the compiler output:

```
mpif90  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c blah   -I/usr/local/dislin/ifc/ -lm  
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info):     relocation     0     has invalid symbol index 10

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
```

The code itself is large so I cannot post it all, but anyway it seems the linking stage is the problem and I think it's my system, not the code.

I'm using the MPICH2 mpif90 1.4.1 wrapper, with gfortran 4.6.3

edit: here's what I send to the command line:

```
         -------------- Build: Debug in K2 (compiler: mpif90 from GNU Fortran Compiler)---------------

    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2common.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2common.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2matrix.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2matrix.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2common_parallel.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2common_parallel.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2eispack.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2eispack.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectxi.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectxi.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsee.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsee.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2convertf.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2convertf.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectyr.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectyr.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectpi.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectpi.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2timestep.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2timestep.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2hydro.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2hydro.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2tests.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2tests.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2maxwell.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2maxwell.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2parameters.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2parameters.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2rotate.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2rotate.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp_VL.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp_VL.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2correctE.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2correctE.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2initialise.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2initialise.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsie.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsie.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2transport.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2transport.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectyr4.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectyr4.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectxp.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectxp.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2fluxes.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2fluxes.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2calcGHi.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2calcGHi.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2output.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2output.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2maxwell2.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2maxwell2.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advecty.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advecty.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2gridi.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2gridi.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2extras.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2extras.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2magnetic.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2magnetic.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2ohms.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2ohms.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsee_ani.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsee_ani.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp_cubic.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp_cubic.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp_chang.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp_chang.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2evolveEB.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2evolveEB.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectx_ppm.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectx_ppm.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2smooth.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2smooth.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2hybrid.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2hybrid.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2grid.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2grid.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectyr2.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectyr2.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsii.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsii.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2unused.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2unused.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2momentsi.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2momentsi.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2colls_ee_gyor.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2colls_ee_gyor.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2single.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2single.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2initial_calcs.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2initial_calcs.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2calcGH.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2calcGH.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2moments.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2moments.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advecty_rot.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advecty_rot.o
    mpif90 -Jobj/Debug/  -w -ffree-line-length-256     -c /home/mark/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectx.F90 -o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectx.o
    mpif90  -o bin/Debug/K2 obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2common.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2matrix.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2common_parallel.o 
    obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2eispack.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectxi.o 
    obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsee.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2convertf.o 
    obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectyr.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectpi.o
     obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2timestep.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2hydro.o 
     obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2tests.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2maxwell.o 
     obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2parameters.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2rotate.o
      obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp_VL.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2correctE.o 
      obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2initialise.o 
      obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsie.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2transport.o 
      obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectyr4.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectxp.o
       obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2fluxes.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2calcGHi.o 
       obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2output.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2maxwell2.o 
       obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advecty.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2gridi.o 
       obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2extras.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2magnetic.o 
       obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2ohms.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsee_ani.o
        obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp_cubic.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectp_chang.o 
        obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2evolveEB.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectx_ppm.o 
        obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2smooth.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2hybrid.o
         obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2grid.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectyr2.o 
         obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2collsii.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2unused.o 
         obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2momentsi.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2colls_ee_gyor.o 
         obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2single.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2initial_calcs.o 
         obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2calcGH.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2moments.o
          obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advecty_rot.o obj/Debug/Dropbox/Codes/K2/K2advectx.o   -I/usr/local/dislin/ifc/ -lm  
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 10
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 11
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 10
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 11
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 20 has invalid symbol index 19
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
    (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 15 seconds)
    1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 15 seconds)
```

Comment: I see neither source files nor object files on the compiler command line. No surprise that you get that error.

Comment: I removed them to make that line easier to read (that' what the "blah" is there for), but I'll edit the post and add the full command line.

Comment: What does `mpif90 -show` shows?

Comment: I still continued to get this error when switching to the intel compiler, even though I was including the file which contained the program. What fixed it was to not use mpif90, but instead pass most of the arguments that mpif90 would use directly to ifort like this:   ifort -I/usr/include/mpich2 -I/usr/include/mpich2 -L/usr/lib -lmpichf90 -lmpichf90 -lmpich -lopa -lmpl -lrt -lcr -lpthread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error I know from cases when I forgot to add the object file for the main program (the one that starts with `program foo` ;-) ). Could it be that you miss that one as well?